# Apache2, PHP5 , Code Igniter and PGSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, apache2, codeigniter

I'm generally familiar with the stack I am encountering an odd problem. When i call a webpage that send a request that makes postgres take long to respond generally because the table is large. My Apache2 hangs no other requests to my website will return, not even web pages that query small tables and were returning all long. They won't even be logged in the appache access.log

Configuration

```
**php.ini**
max_execution_time 300

**apache2.conf**
TimeOut 300
```

When i restart my server the requests that werent logged come through and are served but still the long taking one fails.

My thinking is that one web page should not affect any other request, as each script runs in its own and creates a new connection to the db.

I don't think its the OS because I am developing on a windows laptop (XAMP) and deploying on Debian server. Whether running on live server Debian or my dev localhost the behavior is the same.